# C# scope resolution issues

Tags: c#

I have a base class Shape and subclasses Circle, Triangle. Upon instantiation of a specific shape object I'm adding it to a static database. I want to be able to select any Shape object from within any Shape object but can't seem to find the correct syntax/mechanism to allow for implicit access. I'm trying to avoid repeating every method within each subclass where they would be mostly identical (except for the collection type) by genericizing and consolidating as much as possible into the base class. I'm getting the following errors in line 14:

Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ItemType' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   CS1061  'object' does not contain a definition for 'Items' and no accessible extension method 'Items' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I may be missing something obvious or doing something fundamentally wrong. Would be great to learn how to approach this kind of a task.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Test
{
    public class Shape
    {
        public bool Selected;
        public Type ItemType;
        public object Collection;

        public void Select()
        {
            (ItemType)Collection.Items[0].Selected = true; //Errors
        }
    }
    public class Circle : Shape
    {
        public Circle()
        {
            ItemType = typeof(ShapeList<Circle>);
            Collection = ShapeDb.Circles;
            ShapeDb.Circles.Items.Add(this);
        }
    }
    public class Triangle : Shape
    {
        public Triangle()
        {
            ItemType = typeof(ShapeList<Triangle>);
            Collection = ShapeDb.Triangles;
            ShapeDb.Triangles.Items.Add(this);
        }
    }
    public class ShapeList<T>
    {
        public List<T> Items { get; set; }

        public ShapeList()
        {
            Items = new List<T>();
        }
    }
    public static class ShapeDb
    {
        public static ShapeList<Circle> Circles = new ShapeList<Circle>();
        public static ShapeList<Triangle> Triangles = new ShapeList<Triangle>();
    }
}
```

Comment: A few pointers, `object Collection` is your problem. You expect it to be a Entity/dB Table when you assign it like this `Collection = ShapeDb.Circles;` yet you also expect it to almost be like a ListBox Selection. Remove the Lines of Code with Collection - comment them out and get the basic app working. Then re-evaluate how you wish to store the objects in the database.

Comment: Echoing Jeremy, what does "Collection" inside a "Shape" represent? If I have a Triangle object, why does it contain a Collection of Triangles?

Comment: What's wrong with just having a `List<Shape> selectedShapes` external to these classes?  I mean, if you look up the definition of a "Triangle" or even a "Shape", whether it is _selected or not_ is not really part of what it means to be a Shape.  Whether or not something is selected is typically part of the interaction controller.

Comment: You can't cast to a run-time type. Casting must be done with compile-time types.

Comment: The sentence " I want to be able to select any Shape object from within any Shape object" is the most confusing for me. What do you mean by this?

Comment: Thank you for all the feedback so far and apologies if my question isn't quite clear. This is an ultra simplified version of the full scope, which would be too much for a single thread, but all the pointers are helpful!

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the comments that the collection inside Shape probably doesn't  make sense design-wise but for learning sake you could accomplish this using generics without the need to store the object types.

```
// Recursive generic constraint.  The T type must be a Shape itself.
public class Shape<T> where T : Shape<T>
{
    public bool Selected;

    public ShapeList<T> Collection;

    public void Select()
    {
        Collection.Items[0].Selected = true;
    }
}

public class Circle : Shape<Circle>
{
    public Circle()
    {
        Collection = ShapeDb.Circles;
        ShapeDb.Circles.Items.Add(this);
    }
}

public class Triangle : Shape<Triangle>
{
    public Triangle()
    {
        Collection = ShapeDb.Triangles;
        ShapeDb.Triangles.Items.Add(this);
    }
}

public class ShapeList<T>
{
    public List<T> Items { get; set; }

    public ShapeList()
    {
        Items = new List<T>();
    }
}

public static class ShapeDb
{
    public static ShapeList<Circle> Circles = new ShapeList<Circle>();
    public static ShapeList<Triangle> Triangles = new ShapeList<Triangle>();
}
```

Comment: This looks like the kind of solution I was looking for, thank you! I will follow up as soon as I'm able to test it.